# A word for a symbol which has outlived its origin

Tags: single-word-requests

I am quite sure that there is a word for a symbol which was originated by a real-life, physical prototype but has since then outlived its origin.

Most notable example: the save button with floppy drive on it. Also, to a lesser degree, envelopes in email clients, and so on.

The "anachronism" or "metonymy" are close, but not exactly what I'm searching for.

Comment: I think the ampersand **&** is another example of this; it's Latin **et** in joined-together letters, but we don't use Latin any more.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A [skeuomorph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph) is "a derivative object that retains ornamental design cues to a structure that was necessary in the original."

Comment: You could always go for broke and coin **skeuoglyph**!

Comment: Good word; but it seems to be the opposite of what OP is looking for. Skeuomorphs are used to make the new seem familiar by incorporating familiar, but non-functional design. OP refers to symbols whose appearance is no longer familiar, but whose meanings are retained.

Comment: @Dave, I think you've misread the definition of skeuomorph.  While "make the new seem familiar" is one possible aspect of a skeuomorph, in overall sense the word applies well.  See examples in "Digital skeuomorphs" section of referenced article.

Comment: Thanks a whole lot!! It's what I have been searching for.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for "relic"?  I appreciate that it can mean more than just a symbol.

Comment: 'can mean more than just a symbol.': '*relic*' is not a symbol in the first place. Nor for that matter is '*vestige*.'

Answer (score 1):

You can say the symbol is *[outmoded](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/outmoded)*, since, for example, the floppy disk icon represents a mode of storage no longer in use.

Comment: This is generally true, but I'm looking for a word which applies exactly to symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using "memento".