# Word for anachronistic elements in design style as a function of cultural adoption

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A word for a symbol which has outlived its origin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57164/a-word-for-a-symbol-which-has-outlived-its-origin)

Ok, messy title. Sorry, but I have a memory of reading an article (possibly on Boing Boing) that mentioned this word. Essentially, it refers to the way visual elements in man-made objects are copied from predecessors.

Examples are how cellphones have a phone icon for the classic AT&T phone design that hasn't been used for decades. Or a DVD player/media player that uses a cassette tape icon. And yet another example is the injection molded plastic chairs you can buy at Wal-Mart where they imprint them with fake weave patterns, to mimic the old woven grass style of patio furniture.

Hopefully someone has a clue what I'm thinking of because I can't for the life of me recall this term.

Comment: [This question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57164/a-word-for-a-symbol-which-has-outlived-its-origin) may be somewhat relevant.

Comment: Oh, wow, that's basically a duplicate! Didn't see that earlier... I think there is value in having both questions, though, since they describe the word differently enough that they would capture different sets of search terms.

Comment: Your examples, esp., the molded chairs one, are not skeuomorphic, to the extent that the design is more intentional than vestigial. I would look for a more appropriate term. Let's wait and see. PS: In fact, it appears to me that the semantics are actually reversed. You bring a forgotten/ obsolete pattern and incorporate in the design for the purpose of symbolism,  nostalgia or even a sense of comfort. For me, **retro** has a much closer analogy.

Comment: I looked at the other question and it's specific to symbols, while Skeuomorph (which was the word I was looking for) covers more than just symbols. And the term retro is not at all appropriate here, IMHO.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're looking for *[skeuomorph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph)*: "a product [that] imitates design elements functionally necessary in the original product design, but that becomes ornamental in the new product design."