# What is it called when a word no longer literally describes something?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

An example of this would be the word "Film". Film is no longer the medium that we use to record movies but we still refer to movies as films. What is it called when an older term is used to refer to something but it no longer applies in the literal sense?

Comment: like xerox a copy

Comment: It's called "meaning change" and it's a normal part of language. Think of the fact that we "dial" numbers though the dial is no longer part of the phone.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I can't find it right now, but I'm pretty sure there's another ELU question about this where one of the answers includes some technical term (perhaps derived from ancient Greek) for such usages. Feasibly it was specifically in respect of ***images*** - such as a "cartoon" image of an old-style box camera with a red line drawn through it, to mean ***No filming*** (at a paid performance venue, for example).

Comment: - found it! - [***skeuomorph***.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85297/word-for-anachronistic-elements-in-design-style-as-a-function-of-cultural-adopti) On a question closed as a duplicate of [A word for a symbol which has outlived its origin.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57164/a-word-for-a-symbol-which-has-outlived-its-origin)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't really think this is at all what the OP is looking for.  Look at the article:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph

Comment: @Lordology: What? *Skeuomorph?* I never said it was - in fact, I specifically implied even in my *first* comment (before finding the reference) that it might not be. But the *actual* dup I linked to specifically includes the same reference to ***film*** that OP cites as an example here.

Comment: Oh - I see - It's just when people burst out with _found it!_ it usually seems like they have an answer.  I wasn't sure whether you were relating to your last comment or not.  Simple case of misunderstanding ;)

Comment: It's called a "word".

Comment: Why did you delete your answer? Despite a couple crazy downvoters, your answer described the situation perfectly, semantic drift. Ah, but it is pretty much a dupe,(though your answer is a longer one than there). Give your answer there maybe?

Answer (score -2):

**semantic change**

Also called *semantic shift, lexical change*, and *semantic progression*

[From Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change)

> Semantic change (also semantic shift, semantic progression, semantic
> development, or semantic drift) is the evolution of word usage

There are many different types of semantic change, such as:

> Narrowing: Change from superordinate level to subordinate level. For example, skyline formerly referred to any horizon, but now in the USA, it has narrowed to a horizon decorated by skyscrapers.
>
> Widening: There are many examples of specific brand names being used
> for the general product, such as with Kleenex. Such uses are known as
> generonyms
>
> Metaphor: Change based on similarity of thing. For example, broadcast
> originally meant "to cast seeds out"; with the advent of radio and
> television, the word was extended to indicate the transmission of
> audio and video signals. Outside of agricultural circles, very few use
> broadcast in the earlier sense.
>
> Metonymy: Change based on nearness in space or time, e.g., jaw "cheek"
> → "mandible".
>
> Synecdoche: Change based on whole-part relation. The convention of
> using capital cities to represent countries or their governments is an
> example of this.
>
> Hyperbole: Change from weaker to stronger meaning, e.g., kill
> "torment" → "slaughter"
>
> Meiosis: Change from stronger to weaker meaning, e.g., astound "strike
> with thunder" →
> "surprise strongly".
>
> Degeneration: e.g., knave "boy" → "servant" → "deceitful or despicable
> man".
>
> Elevation: e.g., knight "boy" → "nobleman".

**I'd say this is an example of *semantic metaphor* , where the change is based on the similarity of the thing (film -->  movie)**

See this article from ThoughtCo:

https://www.thoughtco.com/semantic-change-words-1692078

Comment: -1 The transferred sense of film 1. membrane 2. movie picture is an example of one of the phenomena listed here. But the OP describes something different, namely the phenomenon that nowadays films (movies) are not made on a medium resembling film (membrane)..The word refers to a sort of thing, as it has long done. Its meaning hasn't changed. But new such things are not like the old ones.

Answer (score -2):

I like [anachronism](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/anachronism) here, from Dictionary.com

> anachronism [uh-nak-ruh-niz-uh m]
>
> noun
> something or someone that is not in its correct historical or chronological time, especially a thing or person that belongs to an earlier time:
> The sword is an anachronism in modern warfare.

Answer (score -3):

This is  called '***ETYMOLOGICAL MEANING***'.
The etymological meaning is the first meaning which is the base of further semantic development of the word.

According to  Etymology Online:

***film*** (n.)

Old English filmen "membrane, thin skin, foreskin," from West Germanic  *filminjan (source also of Old Frisian filmene "skin," Old English fell  "hide"), 
 extended from Proto-Germanic  *fello(m)"animal hide," from PIE root *pel- (3) "skin, hide."

Sense of "a thin coat of something" is 1570s, extended by 1845 to the coating of chemical gel on photographic plates.

By 1895 this also meant the coating plus the paper or celluloid.

Hence "a motion picture" (1905); sense of "film-making as a craft or art" is from 1920.

Comment: -1 no sources cited

Comment: The OP is not asking about the shift in meaning from membrane to motion picture, but from chemically recorded motion picture to electronically recorded motion picture.

Comment: @Lordology actually, user3072... specifically mentions "Etymology Online" but the answer, unfortunately, is wrong in any case.

Comment: There is no exact answer for the previous questions.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, I mean no sources to prove that 'etymological meaning' is  a thing, and when I Google it apparently it isn't.